# Creating DIV dynamically, is not taking height and width on fly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to create div dynamically based on some calculations.I am able build div's dynamically but the only issue is it's not taking height and width on fly.please any one share their view or code if possible.

Here's the script which i used for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
   function createDiv()
   {
            var totalheight=400;
            var totalwidth = 600;
            var height = 80;
            var width = 40;
            var divheight = totalheight / height;
            var divwidth = totalwidth / width;
            var id=1;

            for(var i=1;i<=divheight;i++)
            {
                var eh=divwidth;
                var fh=1;
                for (var w = 1; w <= divwidth; w++)
                {
                   var div=document.createElement("<div id='"+id+"' style=\"background:#F0E68C;width:'"+width+"'px;height:'"+height+"'px;border:solid 1px #c0c0c0;padding: 0.5em;text-align: center;float:left;\"></div>"); 
                   document.body.appendChild(div);
                   eh=eh+divheight;
                   fh=fh+divheight;
                   id++;
                }
                 var div1=document.createElement("<br/>");
                 document.body.appendChild(div1);
            }     
    }
    </script>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Becouse this `<div>` doesn't contains anything so it doesn't appear, try to append elements to it, or add `min-hegiht`

Comment: did you tried div.setAttribute('height', 'amount')?

Comment: Thanks MGA,i am able to see the DIV's as my output but it's taking some other height and width.can you please elaborate the what your trying to say.It will be more helpful if you give any example.

Comment: Hello varada thank you, the code sample which you have provided is good. But there is no effect on my output

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this.. hope this is what you are trying to do..

```
<html>

<script type="text/javascript" >
 function newDiv(){
            var totalheight=400,ht = 80 , totalwidth = 600 ,wd = 40 ,i;
            var divheight = totalheight / ht;
            var divwidth = totalwidth / wd;
            var id=1;

            for(var i=1;i<=divheight;i++)
            {
                var eh=divwidth;
                var fh=1;
                for (i = 1; i <= divwidth; i++)
                {
                   var div=document.createElement("div")
                   div.setAttribute("id","newDivId"+id)
                   div.setAttribute("class","newDiv")
                   div.style.width =wd+"px";
                   div.style.height =ht+"px";
                   document.body.appendChild(div);
                   eh=eh+divheight;
                   fh=fh+divheight;
                   id++;
                }
                 var div1=document.createElement("<br/>");
                 document.body.appendChild(div1);
            }     
    }
</script>
<style type="text/css">
.newDiv{
    background-color:#F0E68C;
    border:1px solid #c0c0c0;
    padding: 0.5em;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
}
</style>
<body>
    <input type="button" onclick="newDiv()" value="Click Me">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not adding any content to the div so you won't see anything unless you have some visual styles like border to see it on the screen.

There are few things to note here

- If you are setting the height and width inline then specify the unit
  also e.g. `px`, `em` etc.
- Add some visual styles to make is appear on the screen

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e4928/)**

Comment: Thanks Shankar, please check my code which i have edited a minute ago.